# Press-This stopped redirecting to permalink after post publish

Tags: permalinks

I use WordPress’ built in “Press This” feature quite a lot.

I recently installed a new professional paid theme for my site, and for whatever reason this broke the normal behavior of “Press This” in the following way:

– It used to be that after clicking the “Publish” button in the “Press This” editor, the post would be published, and you would then be redirected to its permalink inside the same window.

– Now what happens is that instead of being redirected to the post’s Permalink, I get redirected to a Querystring URL in the following format:
http://www.my-website-url.com/?post_type=post&p=12345

I tried looking into it myself, but I have very limited knowledge in php/javascript/ajax programming, and there is very little detailed documentation on how “Press This” works.

I also contacted the theme developer, but he said he didn’t know what about his theme could have caused this issue with “Press This”, and that he “doesn’t offer support for plugin conflicts”.

Can anyone who knows how “Press This” works help me figure this out?  What could a Theme possibly do that could cause this behavior?

I might be able to figure it out myself eventually if I spend the next WEEK on it, but I figured for someone “in the know” this would probably be quite easy.

Thank you!!

Comment: The URL format you're showing does work (and immediately gets converted on load into "pretty" permalink format). Have you re-saved your permalinks? I only ask because you don't mention having done it. Also, considering that Press This is included with WP Core, I'd think a "professional" WP theme developer ought to have it covered, one way or another. If there really is a conflict between his theme and Press This, he should warn potential buyers, and at a minimum offer money back,

Comment: Hey CK MacLeod, thank you for taking the time to respond! As I don't really know what "re-saving" permalinks is, I'd say the answer is probably no :D Could you please elaborate on what that means? As for the second part I agree with you there and have re-engaged the developer asking him to resolve it as Press This is an integral part of WordPress now, as you said. Don't get me wrong, the theme is otherwise extremely good, which is why I prefer to resolve this issue rather than ask for a refund.

Comment: Just to add, if I do use "Press This" to publish a post, and then I open that post via the standard editor right after, the permalink is there. So it is being generated. I just don't know why it's not being returned back to "Press This" when it's redirected to the published post.

Comment: Re-Saving Permalinks: Go to Settings/Permalinks, click Save Changes - or, to be sure you've adopted new re-write rules, carefully note the current setting if it's custom and unusual-looking, then save back to the WordPress "Plain" default, then save again, but this time with the desired rules. If that doesn't work... then things might get complicated.

Comment: Hey CK! Yeah, I tried that but it didn't work. I still get redirected to the post querystring rather than the permalink. I looked at the source code for `wp-admin/includes/class-wp-press-this.php` and on Line 181 the code is `$redirect = get_post_permalink( $post_id );`. So there is a call to the get_post_permalink() function, but it returns a querystring rather than a permalink. I then looked at the [source code](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_permalink/) for it, but wasn't quite sure which condition gets invoked to return a querystring, and why...

Comment: I'm guessing once I know which condition is getting invoked in get_post_permalink() to return the Querystring, it would then be possible to narrow things down to the list of potential issues in the Theme which would create these conditions. But unfortunately I don't have the knowledge/experience to actually test this hypothesis in practice.

Comment: OK - just double checked with PressThis on my own installation, and the post_type=post&p=[id] string is normal for it (never noticed). Another thing you could try - just on the off chance - is installing PressThis Extended and seeing if it happens to take over the process suitably for you, but, if you've 1) saved permalinks, 2) re-set the PressThis bookmarklet if that's what you're using, and tested it on different targets, and 3) verified the problem doesn't occur with plugins disabled or in other themes, then it would make sense to look at the Theme for any unusual permalink re-writing.

Comment: Well, before switching to my current theme, I was using a WordPress default theme called "Modern Business", and with that theme the "Press This" editor would redirect me to the Permalink of the newly published post, not the Querystring. If you look at the source code of `wp-admin/includes/class-wp-press-this.php` it says in the comments that "Redirect URL. If `$status` is 'publish', this will be the post permalink.". So I'm not sure what you mean when you said it's normal for "Press This" to redirect to querystring, as it seems designed to redirect to the Permalink.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay, so after narrowing the problem down to the function `get_post_permalink()` which gets called by `wp-admin/includes/class-wp-press-this.php` on Line 181, and for some reason returns the Querystring rather than the Permalink when I am using my 3rd party theme, I implemented a workaround which is not ideal, but it works!

I added the following code, starting after Line 181:

```
if ( 'publish' === get_post_status( $post_id ) ) {
    $redirect = get_post_permalink( $post_id ); // at this point the function returned a querystring
/**/
/*START - Attempted fix for not redirecting to Permalinks with 3rd Party Theme*/
/**/
$post = get_post($post_id);
$slug = $post->post_name;
$post_link = $redirect;
$post_link = str_replace("%$post->post_type%", $slug, $post_link);
$post_link = home_url( user_trailingslashit($post_link) );
$redirect = $post_link;
/**/
/*END - Attempted fix for not redirecting to Permalinks with 3rd Party Theme*/
/**/
} elseif {...}
```

So I basically extracted part of the code from get_post_permalink(), and manually added it here to "force" the creation of a permalink from the returned Querystring, after the initial call of `$redirect = get_post_permalink( $post_id );`.

Again, this is far from ideal! It does work, but it's a fix for the symptom and not the root cause.

For now this will do, and I'll just wait for the theme developer to provide a more permanent solution via a theme update!

Once that happens I will update this post with what the theme developer will have to say as to the root cause of this problem to begin with.

Comment: You seem to be aware that this manner of correcting the problem is sub-optimal. If something like this hack is necessary, there is very likely a "WordPress way" to do it (i.e., able to survive upgrades to WP Core and also not likely to cause problems if you switch themes or permalinking), but maybe further discussion should wait until your Theme developer has responded. BTW, did you ever try re-setting (deleting and replacing) the bookmarklet?

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the problems with this, and am keeping backups of all my changes so I can re-apply them easily in case of a WordPress core update. Definitely not optimal, but it's all I have at the moment. As for resetting the Bookmarklet, I haven't actually tried that, but how would could that have any possible connection to `get_post_permalink( $post_id );` returning a Querystring instead of a Permalink on the php end of things? As I understand the bookmarklet is just simple javascript to call press-this.php and applies some pre-filtering.

Comment: Just to make sure, I tried resetting the bookmarklet and tested it with my above fix removed, and the problem came back. So definitely not anything in the Bookmarklet.

Comment: Without actually having my hands on your installation - esp the theme - I'm pretty much restricted to suggesting possible external fixes that also happen to be easy one and potentially of investigative value. In my own history with Press This, I have occasionally need to re-install the bookmarklet after switching themes, but never looked more deeply into why (life being short, WordPress long).

Comment: Oh I wasn't criticizing you in any way, and thank you for taking the time to help me with my problem! I just wasn't sure the Bookmarklet thing could be related, but I did try it nonetheless as per your suggestion, but alas.. it did not help! Appreciate your time! :)

Comment: No offense take! If you do ever get a response from the Theme developer (which Theme, btw? - maybe there's a free version that I can re-produce the problem with), I hope you'll update this post. Also, do take a look at PressThis Extended...

Comment: I am in contact with the theme developer now, and am awaiting to see what he has to say. Will update here once I get any new information. As for PressThis Extended, hasn't that been merged into WordPress core? I checked out the plugin page and it hasn't been updated in 2 years...

Comment: modifying core code is never a good answer, In the long run it might land you into more problems than you have now.Your problem is probably not actually what you think that it is, but probably is caused by not having additional redirect that should probably have happened, and you should probably find the core of the problem as it might create a duplicate content issue with google if you care about such things.

Comment: Hey Mark, thanks for your input! We don't have to deal with so many probabilities as I've narrowed it down very specifically with the aforementioned solution. The core Press-This script is meant to redirect to the URL that's returned by `get_post_permalink()`, and in the case of my 3rd party theme it returns a querystring instead of a permalink. There is no code built in that triggers any "additional" redirects. It's plain and simple, get permalink -> redirect to it.

Comment: If you look at the [source-code](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_permalink/) for the `get_post_permalink()` function, there's an if...else conditional, where the first condition returns a Permalink, and the 'else' condition returns a querystring. So the condition to return a Permalink is:
`if ( !empty($post_link) && ( !$draft_or_pending || $sample ) ) {
        if ( ! $leavename ) {
            $post_link = str_replace("%$post->post_type%", $slug, $post_link);
        }
        $post_link = home_url( user_trailingslashit($post_link) ); } else {return query}`

Comment: For whatever reason, probably having to do with how my 3rd party theme handles post saves, or maybe its metadata handling function during post save make it so those conditions are not met. Perhaps it needs to flag something, or update an extra parameter in the database which for whatever reason (design flaw?) it doesn't do when using Press-This (as it does work with the regular editor). Unfortunately that's as far as I am able to go as I don't know enough to test this. I gave all this information to the theme developer, and hopefully he can come up with the solution which I will update here.